# For any $x$ in distributive lattice $L$, do we have $x = \sup \{a \in At(L) : a \leq x\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, order-theory

Consider the following statement.

> Let $L$ a finite distributive lattice. Then, for any $x \in L$, we
> have $x = \sup  \{a \in At(L) : a \leq x\}$}.

Let $X = \{a \in At(L) : a \leq x\}$. It is clear, by definition,
that $x$ is an upper bound of $X$. I attempted to prove that the statement is true in the following manner.

---

Assume $x \neq \sup  X$. Then there is some $y \in L$ such that $\forall a \in X
: a \leq y$ and $y \leq x$. (If $y \not\leq x$ then $a_j \lor a_k$ is undefined
for $a_j, a_k \in X$, which means $L$ is not a lattice and implies a
contradiction.) Now, if all atoms in $X$ are inferior to a unique element $y$, we
may take the subset $D = X \cup \{0, y\}$, where $0$ is the minimum of $L$.

It is clear that $D$ is a sublattice of $L$, because

$\textit{(a.)}~  a_j \lor a_k = y, a_j \land a_k = 0$, for any
pair of atoms $a_j, a_k \in X$,

$\textit{(b.)} ~ y \lor a_j = y, y \land a_j =
a_j$.

In other words, the supremum and infimum of each pair is included.

It is straightforward to observe that the diamond lattice is a sublattice
of $D$---simply observe its Hasse diagram. But this is a contradiction,
because $D$ is a sublattice of $L$ and $L$ is distributive by assumption. Then
$x = \sup  X$. $\blacksquare$

---

My issue with this proof is indirect. After writing it, I consulted the theory, and the statement is proved in my book *only* for Boolean algebras$-$this is, for distributive *and complemented* finite lattices. Furthermore, the proof provided in the book uses complements to arrive at the conclusion. This had me thinking that perhaps my proof is wrong, and there's some reason I am missing why this could be false if the lattice were not complemented.

Is my proof correct? If not, why?

Comment: Pick the factors of $12$ ordered by divisibility. The atoms are $2$ and $3,$ and $x=4$ is a counterexample.

Comment: How did you go about finding this counter-example? There are infinitely many lattices to choose from.

Comment: I ask because I did try to find counter-examples with no success. And in general I am having trouble finding counter-examples in order theory problems, while people seem to be able to draw them as if from a magic hat!

Comment: It's a pretty standard example - I knew the atoms of a lattice are like primes, and jumped from there. You could, of course, pick the distributive lattice of factors of any $n$ which is not square-free.

Comment: Even without reading the details of the proof, there must be something very wrong. Any chain is a distributive lattice, and if a chain has more than 2 elements, then the join of the only element is itself, and there is at least one element above. What is true for a finite distributive lattice $L$ is that $$x=\bigvee\{j\in J(L):j\leq x\}$$ where $J(L)$ is the set of the join-irreducible elements. In the Boolean setting, the join-irreducible elements turn out to be atoms.